# Google maps is always displayed

Tags: php, google-maps, if-statement

I want to hide the google map if the sql fails:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT melding FROM alarmeringen2010 WHERE `date1` >= DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL -15 MINUTE )");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($result) {
        ?>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&language=nl"></script>
<script> var directionsDisplay; var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();  function initialize() {   directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();   var mapOptions = {     zoom: 7,     center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.7100647, 5.2716885)   };   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),       mapOptions);   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);   directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;   var end = '<?php echo $row[0]; ?>';   var request = {     origin: start,     destination: end,     travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING   };   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {     if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {       directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);     }   }); }  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);      </script>
<div style="width:70%;height:600px;">
        <div id="control"  style="margin-left:-30000px">
                <select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
                        <option  value="gerard brandweg 3 enkhuizen, nederland">enkhuizen</option>
                </select>
                <select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
                        <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>, nederland">enkhuizen</option>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>, nederland">enkhuizen</option>
                </select>
        </div>
        <div id="directions-panel"></div>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
<?php
};?>
```

The if statement is still loading the html and script when it fails.

Comment: `$result` can be intepreted as TRUE if the query doesn't fail. You can use `mysql_num_rows ($result)` to know number of returned rows.
But please, use mysqli_* API instead of mysql_ which is deprecated

Comment: Failure is not the same thing as returning 0 rows. What do you mean exactly? You probably want `if ($row)`.

Comment: @jeroen thank you thats what i wanted. Its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You can count the entries in the `$row` array.

```
if (count($row) > 0) {
```

Instead of your current

```
if ($result) {
```